# What character range would this represent (regular expression)?

Tags: regex

Recently I came across a character range that was the following:

```
[/-+]
```

My very simple question is, is this even a valid character range? If so, what range of characters would it match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a correct range.. it would have to be `[+-/]` since `+` comes before `/` in the ASCII table.

Speaking of the ASCII table, the `[+-/]` would match `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`, or `/`

Here's some test cases (JavaScript):

```
var r = /[+-\/]/;
r.test('foo'); // false
r.test('foo+'); // true
r.test('foo/'); // true
r.test('foo.'); // true
r.test('foo,'); // true
r.test('foo-'); // true
```